# Reduce spacing between the top and chapter title

Tags: spacing

I'm using this template - http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/textprocessing/ThesisStyle1.1/

I'm trying to change the space between the chapter title and the top of the page. I want to reduce it a title bit but can't figure out what part to change.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Really it's better to make a self contained example rather that refer to off site archives, but anyway as far as I can see that class just inputs the standard `book` class and inherits the chapter format from there.

`book` uses the following two macros for the numbered and star form respectively. The space at the top is set at 50pt but you could adjust to whatever you want.

```
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}

\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother
```